# Simulating snowfall in Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#

I'm quite new in C# and I want to creating something like falling snow (dots) in C# using Windows Forms.

I was already able to create the snowflakes at the top of the screen (I want to create new dot every 0,1s, at random x-position of Form and write down every snowflake's position into the List(Point) and with every Tick of timer (0,1s) I want the snowflake to change its position by 3px down and 1-3px right)

But I have the problem with refreshing the snowflakes positions. I don't know how to acces each snowflake in the List to Randomize its new position. 
I tried foreach, but it gives me error, that says I cannot change variable in foreach.

Example:

```
foreach (var snowflake in snowflakeList)            
            {
               snowflake.Y += 3;
               snowflake.X += moveRandom.Next(1, 4);
            }
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I divide List(Point) of snowflakes into invdividual snowflakes, so I could change position of every single dot separately?

Thank you :-)

Comment: use a regular `for` loop if you want to change the elements of the `snowflakeList`

Comment: What is the type of snowflake object?

Comment: Yeah, is `snowflake` a `struct`?

Comment: snowflake is Point. Every tick I create:

Comment: Point snowflake = new Point(positionRandom.Next(1,ActiveForm.Width), 1);
            snowflakeList.Add(snowflake);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is just to use the index of the collection:

```
for (int i = 0; i < snowflakeList.Count; i++)            
{
    var snowflake = snowflakeList[i];
    snowflake.Y += 3;
    snowflake.X += moveRandom.Next(1, 4);
    snowflakeList[i] = snowflake;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for me... It looks like I have to change the snowflake variable directly, not only create new variable. Because the next step, I'm using Refresh() and Form1_Paint, where I'm drawing dots on positions of objects in snowflakeList... Like foreach (var snowflake in snowflakeList) { x = snwflake.X; y = snowflake.Y; g.DrawRectangle(myPen, x,y,1,1)} Is there any way I can change the snowflake position directly in the List?

Comment: The Form1_1 Paint is new private method and I cannot use the var snowflake I created in timer1_Tick method..

Comment: You are making the same mistake that the OP is making.  Except that you now prevent the compiler from telling him that he's doing it wrong.  The snowflake variable is a **copy** of the struct that's stored in the list.  Your code updates the copy, not the value in the list.  You have to store it back.

Comment: When I change the copy (in for cycle), the next time I use for() the copy is on its original position... and that is my question. How can I change the position of the struct in the list instead of copy?

Comment: @user1791823 as Hans said "You have to store it back". e.g. Add `snowflakeList[i] = snowflake;` to the end of that loop.

Comment: lol, yep. I missed a line of code. Sorry about that, edited to actually work now.

Answer (score 0):

As Andrews answer use a for loop, but as the list is of Points (a value type) you would need to reference the Point in the list directly rather than make a copy of it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < snowflakeList.Count; i++)            
{
    snowflakeList[i].Y += 3;
    snowflakeList[i].X += moveRandom.Next(1, 4);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tried this. It gives me error: Error 1 Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Drawing.Point>.this[int]' because it is not a variable